# Projection of $\vec{A}$ on $\vec{B}$

Tags: vectors, inner-products, 3d

I have two vectors:

$A: \{51.031, -102.062, 51.031\}\ (|A|= 125)$

$B: \{2, -4, -1\}\ (|B| =\sqrt{21}\approx 4.58)$

I am trying to find the amount of $\vec{A}$ in the $\vec{B}$ direction, so I used dot product with the coordinate method:

$(x_1 \times x_2+y_1 \times y_2+z_1 \times z_2)$

$([2 \times 51.031]+ [-4 \times -102.062]+ [-1 \times 51.031]) = 459.279$

If the dot product is supposed to find the magnitude of a vector that is pointing in the direction of another vector, how do I get a result that's more than $3$ times the length of the longest vector?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnitude of $A$ in $B$'s direction (i.e. the magnitude of the projection of $A$ onto $B$) is given by $\frac{A\cdot B}{|B|},$ not $A\cdot B.$

You can see that $A\cdot B$ is wrong by units, too, since it has the units of $A$ times $B,$ rather than $A.$ If we situate $B$ on the $x$-axis, we want $|A|\cos\theta,$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $A$ and $B.$ Recall that the dot product is given by $A\cdot B=|A||B|\cos\theta,$ so $\frac{A\cdot B}{|B|}=|A|\cos\theta,$ which is what we want.